# Android/Java: use method from prior SDK, undefined in current SDK

Tags: java, android, compilation, compiler-errors

Developing for Android, I'm targetting SDK 18 which no longer contains the method "setPluginsEnabled" (websettings). I would like to use this method if the user is running an older SDK (`if version <= 4.2, websettings.setPluginsEnabled(true)`), but I'm not sure if it's possible to suppress a "method undefined" error.

@SuppressLint("NewApi") doesn't work here

EDIT: I realize there is now a replacement method for `setPluginsEnabled` (`setPluginState`), but I'm still curious if there is a way to suppress if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`method undefined` means compiler cannot physically find this method at the SDK you provided. I suppose, you've attached SDK > 4.2 to your project. It cannot be supressed, you should use older SDK with your project, if you would like to use this method. Try to use `targetSDK = 17`

Comment: right, 4.2 is SDK 17 and I am targeting SDK 18. So it sounds like I should tell the compiler to look for this method in a previous SDK somehow?

Comment: @bababooey you might be targeting API level 18, but which version are you compiling with? - thats the one that matters

Comment: @panini compiling with 18 as well. I specified this in the project settings. Is it possible to compile a specific block of code with a specific SDK?

Comment: @bababooey try to use `targetSDK = 17`, removed in 18, deprecated since 9

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the few methods that has actually been removed instead of just being deprecated.
If you want to compile your code using setPluginsEnabled then you need to use Android 4.2.2 to compile it (API 17). Before API 17 the method has just been deprecated.

You need to set the build target to Android 4.2.2 or lower:
[image]

Comment: It actually still works up to 4.2, but yes they did remove it. Looks like in 4.3, `webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);` will work though

Comment: he doesn't need to set target to 8. At version 9 this method was just declared as Deprecated, but still can be used.